# Retrieving Previous Values in For Each Loop Reference &$value

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, reference

Here's what my `$array` looks like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [SKU] => SKU_1
            [ProductIDRef] => 45645-12
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [SKU] => SKU_2
            [ProductIDRef] => 43445-45
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [SKU] => SKU_2
            [ProductIDRef] => 
        )
)
```

As you can see in Array `[1]` it contains the same `SKU` value as the one in Array `[2]`.

But the issue is, even though Array `[2]` has the same `SKU` as Array `[1]`, Array `[2]` does not have a value for `ProductIDRef`.

What I'm looking to do is reference previous arrays in my `foreach` loop -- in the example above Array `[1]` needs to pass to Array `[2]`.

If the same `SKU` value from a previous iteration is found (`SKU_2`), insert the missing (or `NULL`) `ProductIDRef` IN Array `[2]` resulting in:

```
[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [SKU] => SKU_2
        [ProductIDRef] => 43445-45
    )
```

Looping it with a `foreach` using `&$` to modify the original `$array`

```
foreach($array as $key => &$value)
{
// if previous SKU value is found . . . 
// $value['ProductIDref'] = $previousProductIDRefValue;
}
```

I've tried the common `foreach` tactics, setting `$f = 0;` before the loop and incrementing it with `$f+;` immediately before the end of the loop.

```
$f = 0;
foreach($array as $key => &$value)
{
$value['customkey'] = $f;
$f++;
}
```

This works, and returns `$array` like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [ProductID] => 182040460699
            [SKU] => SKU_1
            [ProductIDRef] => 132438205662
            [customkey] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [ProductID] => 182040460699
            [SKU] => SKU_2
            [ProductIDRef] => 132438205662
            [customkey] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [ProductID] => 182040460699
            [SKU] => SKU_3
            [ProductIDRef] => 
            [customkey] => 3
        )
)
```

I can conditionally set new values to my array, or modifying existing values

```
    $value['customkey'] = $f;

    if ($f == 2) {
    ///// set new `key => value` pair in Array [2] 
    // $value['status'] = 'unpublished';
    ///// modify the value of ProductIDRef in Array [2]
    // $value['ProductIDRef'] = 'inserted_value';
    }

    $f++;
```

But doing something like `$value['ProductIDRef'] = $value[1]['ProductIDRef'];` does not work.

This is just what I've attempted as a test of how the php `&$` reference operator functions.. additionally, even though it failed, this test makes the assumption that I *know* exactly which key in the indexed array I'm looking to reference back to and get its value --- rather than what I am actually trying to do which is search or reference every each `SKU` and `ProductIDRef` keys in the array to detect a pair and insert it's value.

Is there a way to do this using a `&$` `foreach` loop, or must I do something different, such as split the arrays up and reference them individually (suggestions on how to best do this will also be accepted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
$arr = array(
    array
    (
        "id" => 1,
        "SKU" => 'SKU_1',
        "ProductIDRef" => '45645-12'
    ),
    array
    (
        "id" => 2,
        "SKU" => 'SKU_2',
        "ProductIDRef" => '43445-45'
    ),
    array
    (
        "id" => 3,
        "SKU" => 'SKU_2',
        "ProductIDRef" => null
    )
);

foreach( $arr as $key => $value ) {
    //Check if current item's ProductIDRef is empty or null
    //Check if prev entry exist AND SKU is the same
    if ( ( $value[ "ProductIDRef" ] == "" || $value[ "ProductIDRef" ] == null ) && ( isset( $arr[ $key - 1 ] ) && $arr[ $key - 1 ][ "SKU" ] == $value[ "SKU" ] ) ) {
        $arr[ $key ][ "ProductIDRef" ] = $arr[ $key - 1 ][ "ProductIDRef" ];
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $arr );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [SKU] => SKU_1
            [ProductIDRef] => 45645-12
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [SKU] => SKU_2
            [ProductIDRef] => 43445-45
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [SKU] => SKU_2
            [ProductIDRef] => 43445-45
        )

)
```

Comment: Yes! This even works with `&$` to perform other things whilst doing this.

Comment: Got it how I wanted with your help! Thank you. Placement of the above statement and any others in the loop were crucial as well.